# after compiling gcc 5.4.0 what header folders to export

Tags: c++, c, gcc, centos7, toolchain

I have compiled gcc 5.4.0 (make, make install into non root folder) and have exported it to anther machine of the same base distro. however when I try to compile a `hello world` on the 2nd machine I get an error for `stdio.h` and that cascades to `cstdio` etc.

for gcc I used `configure --prefix=/home/mybin --bindir=/home/mybin/bin --libdir=/home/mybin/lib` etc for all available folders as per --help.

On the gcc compile machine it seems the source folder `/home/tmp/gcc-5.4.0/libstdc++-v3/include` was installed into the `--includedir=/home/mybin/include` folder with all the sub directories.

Searching for `stdio.h` on the 5.4.0 compiling machine I get several folders that contain a version of `stdio.h`.

```
/home/tmp/gcc-5.4.0/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/stdio.h
/home/tmp/gcc-5.4.0/libstdc++-v3/include/c_compatibility/stdio.h
/home/tmp/gcc-5.4.0/fixincludes/tests/base/rtldef/stdio.h
/home/tmp/gcc-5.4.0/fixincludes/tests/base/stdio.h
/home/tmp/gcc-5.4.0/libssp/ssp/stdio.h
/home/tmp/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/cpp/usr/include/stdio.h
```

and the search of the `--prefix=/home/mybin/` returns

```
/home/mybin/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.4.0/include/ssp/stdio.h
/home/mybin/include/c++/5.4.0/tr1/stdio.h
/home/mybin/include/c_compatibility/stdio.h
```

So I copied the ``--prefix=/home/mybin/` folder to the new machine and tried to use

```
gcc -Wall -I/home/mybin/include/c_compatibility /home/myuser/test.c -o /home/myuser/hello
```

this gives

```
In file included from /home/myuser/test.c:3:0:
/home/mybin/include/c_compatibility/stdio.h:29:18: fatal error: cstdio: No such file or directory
```

BUT I do have

```
/home/mybin/include/c++/5.4.0/tr1/cstdio
/home/mybin/include/c++/5.4.0/cstdio
/home/mybin/include/c_std/cstdio
/home/mybin/include/c/cstdio
```

so updated to

```
gcc -Wall -I/home/mybin/include/c_compatibility -I/home/mybin/include/c_std  /home/myuser/test.c -o /home/myuser/hello
In file included from /home/mybin/include/bits/c++config.h:482:0,
                 from /home/mybin/include/c_std/cstdio:44,
                 from /home/mybin/include/c_compatibility/stdio.h:29,
                 from /home/myuser/test.c:3:
/home/mybin/include/bits/os_defines.h:39:22: fatal error: features.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

BUT I do have `/home/mybin/include/c++/5.4.0/parallel/features.h`

```
gcc -Wall -I/home/mybin/include/c_compatibility -I/home/mybin/include/c_std  /home/myuser/test.c -o /home/myuser/hello
In file included from /home/mybin/include/bits/c++config.h:482:0,
                 from /home/mybin/include/c_std/cstdio:44,
                 from /home/mybin/include/c_compatibility/stdio.h:29,
                 from /home/myuser/test.c:3:
/home/mybin/include/bits/os_defines.h:39:22: fatal error: features.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

gcc -Wall -I/home/mybin/include/c_compatibility -I/home/mybin/include/c_std -I/home/mybin/include/c++/5.4.0/parallel /home/myuser/test.c -o /home/myuser/hello
In file included from /home/mybin/include/bits/c++config.h:482:0,
                 from /home/mybin/include/c_std/cstdio:44,
                 from /home/mybin/include/c_compatibility/stdio.h:29,
                 from /home/myuser/_test.c:3:
/home/mybin/include/bits/os_defines.h:44:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if __GLIBC_PREREQ(2,15) && defined(_GNU_SOURCE)
                   ^
In file included from /home/mybin/include/c_compatibility/stdio.h:29:0,
                 from /home/myuser/_test.c:3:
/home/mybin/include/c_std/cstdio:96:1: error: unknown type name 'namespace'
 namespace std
 ^
/home/mybin/include/c_std/cstdio:97:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token
 {
 ^
/home/mybin/include/c_std/cstdio:155:1: error: unknown type name 'namespace'
 namespace __gnu_cxx
 ^
/home/mybin/include/c_std/cstdio:156:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token
 {
 ^
/home/mybin/include/c_std/cstdio:181:1: error: unknown type name 'namespace'
 namespace std
 ^
/home/mybin/include/c_std/cstdio:182:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token
 {
 ^
/home/myuser/_test.c:7:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
 main()
 ^
/home/myuser/test.c: In function 'main':
/home/myuser/test.c:9:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'printf' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     printf("Heh now");
     ^
/home/myuser/_test.c:9:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf'
/home/myuser/_test.c:9:5: note: include '<stdio.h>' or provide a declaration of 'printf'
```

I have tried exporting LD config flags as well

How do I know what folder to export and to other machines made from the same base image so I can compile with this version. Why are the includes not being found or getting confused?

I am using centos7

Comment: _"I get an error"_ - So what error do you get? Which include directory are you pointing to? What include directories exist?

Comment: a `fatal stdio.h not found`error, no directories are included as none have been exported to the `--prefix=myfolder` sub directories as specified in the ./configure.  I do have several folders in the 5.4.0 machine that are in the original untar'd src folder. Hence my question.

Comment: What was your configure command? As others hinted, if installed in usr/local, prepend /usr/local/bin to PATH and lib or lib64 to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. It uses your configure to find headers

Comment: @tim18 the gcc ./configure --prefix=/mybin --bindir=/mybin/bin etc, with bindir in $PATH.  updating LD_LIBRARY_PATH had no effect.

Comment: Did you make then sudo make install?

Comment: @tim18, no, why would I need sudo if I am installing in to a custom folder owned by the compiling user (as per the prefix?) it is not going into root folders. thx Art

Comment: Your question currently says: `--bindir=/home/mybinbin` — is that a typo for `--bindir=/home/mybin/bin`?  If so, why did you bother with `--bindir` and `--libdir` since the values specified are the defaults when `--prefix=/home/mybin`.  If you manually specify all the sub-directories, you are making life error-prone. If you did mean what the question says, I have to ask "why" — why did you change the default locations of the software relative to the prefix directory?  It seems likely to make life harder than it would be otherwise. JFTR, I compile GCC with `--prefix=/some/where` and no subdirs.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes was a typo now fixed, and I did it for completeness. Why would more detail to the compiler make it more error prone? can you expand as I have never read anything to say do not specify both.  My assumption here is that the `make install` will explicitly place any known file type in a specific tagged folder, ie `libdir, docs etc` and anything unusual or not known by the code authors will be placed in a prefix/folder not covered in the `configure --help`, is this incorrect?